# mouse stuck after resumption from suspend

Tags: 10.04, mouse, battery, suspend-resume, tablet

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 on a Gateway TA1 convertable tablet PC.  After I suspend by closing the lid, and resume by reopening the lid, I cannot use my trackpad mouse anymore.  How can I fix this?

UPDATE:
xinput --list output

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                     id=2 [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer               id=4 [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Macintosh mouse button emulation         id=11 [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                    id=3 [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard              id=5 [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                             id=6 [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                             id=7 [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                             id=8 [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard             id=9 [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: can you run the command `xinput --list` after this happens and attach the output please

Comment: Hi @Nick HS, thanks for the troubleshooting step.  I have attached the output requested

Comment: I still have this same problem 2 years later.

Answer (score 2):

This is certainly a bug - I suggest you report it by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, entering `ubuntu-bug` in the box, and following the instructions from there.

Comment: +1 thanks I will try this the next time I have access to my laptop.

Comment: By the way what about the xinput --list output tells you this is a bug?  Is there any specific info you have or do you just also have a hunch it's a bug?

Comment: Well it's something that clearly should work in a certain way, but doesn't. That makes it a bug. Whether it gets fixed is another matter, but reporting a bug is the first step to that.

Comment: This comment is helpful but it's not so much a solution to my problem as a suggestion to ask someone else.

Answer (score 1):

There is a helpful solution to this problem that works at:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=471855

```
sudo apt-get install uswsusp
```

Now, test out suspend to see if it works:

```
sudo s2ram
```

If this does not work, you can use

```
sudo s2ram --force
```

Next, try out hibernate:

```
sudo s2disk
```